# Change Anaconda Interpreter

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

My system has a set-up python environment (2.7) to work with certain programs, and I also want to install Miniconda3 for Python 3.6.

When I call `python` in terminal, it will start the system python from `/usr/bin/python`. To achieve this, I removed the `python` symbolic link in `~/miniconda/bin/`.

Now, when I execute `conda` in terminal, it gives me the following error,

```
-bash: /home/me/miniconda/bin/conda: /home/me/miniconda/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I understand that this is because I remove the anaconda python symbolic link. But is there a way to hack anaconda to use `~/miniconda/bin/python3` as its python interpreter?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution***

I don't have to delete `python` symbolic link in `~/miniconda/bin/`, and instead, in the `~/.bashrc` file, I need to change my conda path to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/miniconda/bin
```

After doing this, when I call `python`, it's actually executing the `python` program in `/usr/bin/`. `conda` command will execute `~/miniconda/bin/conda` program.